# Interpretation of limit definition of complex differentiability.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

A complex function is defined as $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable at $z_0$ if $$f'(z)=\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$ exists. How can this be interpreted as a function of two vairables? I.e., if $x+iy=(x,y)$, $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then how would I re-write this limit?

My attempt: 
Let f(z) be $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable at $z_0$, and let $f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$. Then, we say $f$ is differentiable if $u(x,y) +a|x-x_0|+b|y-y_0|+o(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ and $v(x,y) +c|x-x_0|+d|y-y_0|+o(x-x_0,y-y_0)$. I'm trying to re-formulate the expression above in a similar manner, but I'm having trouble converting between the two.

Something I think might be related is that if $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable, then the limit set of the function $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$ is the circle centered at $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0)$ of radius $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z_0)$. However, I don't know how to prove this either. I would appreciate it if anyone could show me how to prove this aswell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What issues have you been having with rewriting it?  What progress have you made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to interpret it as a function of two variables?" you asked.

Well indeed it is already a function of two (real) variables or one complex variable.
When it comes to differentiability a function of two real variables (or one complex variable, that is the same thing) can be analyzed under two kinds of differentiabilities: $\mathbb{R}$-differentiability and $\mathbb{C}$-differentiability.

A function of two real variables $f: \mathbb{R}^2\supseteq A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2, z \mapsto f(z)$ is $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable at a given point $z_0=(x_0,y_0)$ when its displacement at that point ($\Delta f_{z_0}: A-z_0\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2,\Delta z\mapsto f(z)-f(z_0)$) under a general displacement of the independent variables $z-z_0$ (usually indicated by $\Delta z$) has main component that is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (restricted to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ made up of those $\Delta z$'s that send $z_0$ in a point of the domain $A$ of the function $f$, that is, $A-z_0$):

$$f(z)=f(z_0)+D_{z_0}\Delta z+o(\lvert\Delta z\rvert)\tag{1}$$

This main component (extended by $\mathbb{R}$-linearity to the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is, the said $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator) is called $\mathbb{R}$-differential of the function $f$ at $z_0$: $df_{z_0}: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2, dz\mapsto D_{z_0}dz$, where $dz$ is its independent variable usually indicated in that way and named *virtual* (in the sense that it is not always admissible for $(1)$ to have sense) *displacement* to distinguish it from $\Delta z$, the "admissible" displacement.

This is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so for its complete determination at most two of its values are needed (in the sense that if it is non-singular two values are needed, else less). If we are given its values at $dz=(1,0)$ and $dz=(0,1)$, let's say $a=df_{z_0}(1,0)$ and $b=df_{z_0}(0,1)$, then we can rewrite $(1)$ as
$$f(z)=f(z_0)+a\Delta x+b\Delta y+o(\lvert\Delta z\rvert)\tag{2}$$

where $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are the $\mathbb{R}$-linear components of $\Delta z$ w.r.t. the chosen vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ respectively.
Notice that we can choose equivalently other vectors $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent.

What's important to remember before turning our attention to the $\mathbb{C}$-differentiability is that in $\mathbb{R}$-differentiability no restrictions have been made about the kind of linear operator.

The definition of $\mathbb{C}$-differentiability of $f$ is the same as that of its $\mathbb{R}$-differentiability with the exception that where you read $\mathbb{R}$-linear it must be now read $\mathbb{C}$-linear. If you do what I say, you'll notice that this happens only at "$\mathbb{R}$-linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$" that now becomes "$\mathbb{C}$-linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$". This means that equation $(1)$ is valid, with $D_{z_0}$ being now a $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator.

The $\mathbb{C}$-linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the operators "multiplication of a vector by a complex scalar" and nothing more: this is because $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space is monodimensional, so there cannot be more $\mathbb{C}$-linear operators on it as there are $\mathbb{C}$-scalars. Each of them is characterized uniquely by a complex scalar and so by two real parameters: the relative increment of the length and the oriented angular displacement of the transformed vector w.r.t. to the vector on which they are applied. Notice that this parameters do not depend on the "argument".

You can also check that they are also $\mathbb{R}$-linear as operators on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This means that we can use also equation $(2)$ that was derived by $(1)$ with the assumpion that $D_{z_0}$ were $\mathbb{R}$-linear, because as said $\mathbb{C}$-linearity is a special $\mathbb{R}$-linearity. The purpose is to see what constraints are to be imposed on the chosen values (the vectors $a$ and $b$) of the $\mathbb{R}$-differential to make it a $\mathbb{C}$-differential, that is when it is imposed that the differential must be $\mathbb{C}$-linear instead of $\mathbb{R}$-linear. Then let's try to go from $(2)$ to $(1)$, where $D_{z_0}$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.
$$f(z)=f(z_0)+a\Delta x+b\Delta y+o(\lvert\Delta z\rvert)=f(z_0)+a\Delta x+\frac{b}{i}i\Delta y+o(\lvert\Delta z\rvert)=f(z_0)+D_{z_0}\Delta z+o(\lvert\Delta z\rvert)$$

Being $\Delta x+i\Delta y=\Delta z$, it results that must be:
$$\frac{b}{i}=a\tag{3}$$

that is, $b$ must be at $\pi$ radians from $a$ (and $D_{z_0}=a$). This equation is known as Cauchy-Riemann equation.

On the contrary, you can proceed from the other direction. If you know that $D_{z_0}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (that is, a complex number) it is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that takes each vector to a vector whose length has a relative increment of $A$ and whose angular position has been displaced by $\theta$, where $A$ and $\theta$ characterize completely the $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator, that is $a=A(\cos\theta+i \sin\theta)$ being the transformation of $1$ and $b=A(-\sin\theta+i \cos\theta)$ being the transformation of $i$. So $b$ is displaced by $\pi$ radians from $a$, $a=b/i$. Putting this into $(2)$, you get $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

To start i will rewrite your limit in the form:
$$f'(z) = \lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z+\Delta z)- f(z)}{\Delta z}$$
Notice that $$z = x+iy$$
And so you can think, for now, of $z=z(x,y)$. My goal in this approach is to get an expression for $\Delta z$. Notice that, as $\Delta z$ approaches $0$, we can write as $\Bbb{d}z$. The increment of a function of two variables is given by:
$$\Bbb{d}z = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\Bbb{d}x + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\Bbb{d}y$$
Now, since $z_x = 1$ and $z_y = i$, you will see that:
$$\Bbb{d}z = \Bbb{d}x + i \Bbb{d}y$$
And this is fundamental. Applying it to the limit, and using the fact that $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, we will get to:
$$f'(z) = g(x,y) = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0\\ \Delta y \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y) - u(x,y)}{\Delta x + i \Delta y} + i \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0\\ \Delta y \rightarrow 0} \frac{v(x+\Delta x, y + \Delta y) - v(x,y)}{\Delta x + i \Delta y}$$
And here we are, with infinite ways of making $z$ approach $z_0$. I believe the equation above should explain to you "how to rewrite the limit and interpret it as a function of two variables".